# Ubuntu 20.04 And Intel 10th Gen Processor

Tags: 20.04, intel

I have bought the preinstalled Ubuntu mini-desktop a week ago and the vendor has just notified me that they have to install 18.04 on my machine due to some instability Ubuntu 20.04 has on Intel 10th gen processors (my order is a 10th Gen i9 10880).

I couldn't find any clue on the net. So, I really appreciate any advice and if some people possibly could share their experience and knowledge here.

I am confused and not really sure if I want to continue with that order or just drop it.

Comment: I recall reading stuff about Dells in the last couple of weeks, but I can't be more specific than suggesting glancing through the last couple of UWN's (Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter) as the articles are probably in there (lenovo I think was mentioned too, but I took little interest beyond what I needed to learn for new purposes)

Comment: You should just test it. Make a Live USB, let it run, see what happens.

Comment: @mikewhatever, I wish I could but the machine is not delivered yet. So, I am asking here to find out what I should do with my order. I still have a chance of cancelling my order and get a full refund.

Comment: The problem with your question is the vagueness. An unknown vendor had an unknown instability on an unknown PC model with an unknown hardware. All you could provide is the CPU model, but an instability may not be related to it. With so many unknowns, and no way to test, you may want to cancel, and get a refund.